# Rewrite WordPress Url from root to subfolder without moving files

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, directory

I have a WordPress installation in the root folder "example.com/". I want the url to be "example.com/blog". (Rewrite from root to folder "/blog/")

Is it possible to do this without moving files via FTP to this actual directory? I would like to do the rewrite just via wp-config and via .htaccess.

Comment: See [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/).

Comment: Thanks but this process requires moving files. I'm looking for a .htaccess only way.